# what exception rule to use with unselected radio buttons to produce exception dialog

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to produce an error exception when the user has not selected an option with radio buttons. The code I have does not produce the error exception message boxes. I am not getting any coding errors as the syntax seems to be fine, just that the code is not producing the desired procedure.

```
Try
        SelectedServiceDeciaml = CostSelectedService
        TotalDecimal = SelectedServiceDeciaml + TotalDecimal
        AmountAllServicesTextBox2.Text = TotalDecimal.ToString("c")
    Catch DiscountException As ArgumentException When (Discount10RadioButton5.Checked  = False AndAlso Discount20RadioButton6.Checked = False AndAlso NoDiscountRadioButton7.Checked = False)
        MessageBox.Show("A discount amount must be selected.", "Data entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        With NoDiscountRadioButton7
            .Focus()
            .Select()
        End With
    End Try
```

Comment: Put this in a method an do the logic in there

Comment: I am pretty new to this, sorry for the noob question, but what is a method?

Comment: Create a new class that inherits from system.exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a custom exception for your case, but if you want to create a custom exception then I would create a new class that inherits from the built in class: `System.Exception`. If you want to go that route I could give an example to you.

```
 Try
    SelectedServiceDeciaml = CostSelectedService
    TotalDecimal = SelectedServiceDeciaml + TotalDecimal
    AmountAllServicesTextBox2.Text = TotalDecimal.ToString("c")

    If (Discount10RadioButton5.Checked = False AndAlso Discount20RadioButton6.Checked = False AndAlso NoDiscountRadioButton7.Checked = False) Then
    MessageBox.Show("A discount amount must be selected.", "Data entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Information)
With NoDiscountRadioButton7
    .Focus()
    .Select()  
    End If 
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured... Heres the error: " & ex.ToString)
  End Try
```

Comment: That worked. So you have to put the catch after the if statement? would it be the same for case statements as well?

Comment: Correct, but Try/Catch statements can be anywhere in code. Basically the idea is to catch something if something should fail. When it does in the catch section, you can handle this if needed to be.

Comment: You can also have nested Try/Catch statements as well, but not usually recommended from my point of view.

Comment: yeah it did help also it makes sense that if I am trying to run a catch before a condition is passed it will not work, helps me understand how this programming thing works!